# Injection of Generic Services in Angular

Tags: angular

Will Angular inject more than one instance of a generic Service if it is invoked across Component constructors using different Types?

I have a lot of Services that are going to provide the same functionality for different classes that all inherit from the same base class. I'd like to use Typescript's generic pattern `MyService<T extends BaseClass>` to handle this.

But I don't know how it jives with Angular's injector:

1. Will the Angular injector create *more than one instance* of this service if it's injected into different components with different Types?
2. Will the injector inject the *same instance* if it is called with the same type?

Code:

```
@Injectable
export class MyService<T> {
    ...
}

@Component
export class ComponentA {
    constructor(alphaService MyService<Alpha>) {}   <--Instance 1
}

@Component
export class ComponentB {
    constructor(betaService MyService<Beta>) {}   <----Instance 2?
}

@Component
export class ComponentA1 {
    constructor(alphaService MyService<Alpha>) {}  <---Instance 1?
}
```

Is this legal?  Does the injector know to create two instances of MyService?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a simple solution:

```js
// service and models
export class User {
  firstName: string
}

export class Admin {
  lastName: string
}

@Injectable()
export class GenericService<T>{
  item: number = Math.random();
  GetAll(): Array<T> {
    let output = [];
    console.log(this.item); // each instance has own value
    return output;
  }
}
```

Then set your service in module through useFactory:

```js
providers: [
  { provide: 'UserService', useFactory: () => (new GenericService<User>()) },
  { provide: 'AdminService', useFactory: () => (new GenericService<Admin>()) },
],
```

and inject your service with @Inject decorator:

```js
constructor(
  @Inject('UserService') private userService: GenericService<User>,
  @Inject('AdminService') private adminService: GenericService<Admin>
) { }
```

Keep in mind it is better to use [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) ( [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html) is deprecated) for your provider token.I have used string just for simplicity.

Comment: Just a note: `OpaqueToken` is deprecated. Use [**`InjectionToken`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/InjectionToken-class.html) instead.

Comment: So, how do you inject the `HttpClient` (or `HttpModule`) object for constructor like this one `constructor(private http:HttpClient)`

Comment: Use `@Inject("UserService") private userService: any`. if it requires a lot of work to build the GenericService and all the Typed implementations. In my case I would need to have dozens of Typed classes in order to get started with our upgrade. So I just treated userService as any in order to Inject the angularJS service with type any.

Comment: what about `class UserService extends GenericService<User>`?  since UserService is an actual class it could be injected separately, right?

Answer (score 5):

An additional instance won't be created for generics. As it is stated [here](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators/issues/33#issuecomment-223863311), `reflect-metadata` (which is used by Angular 2 decorators to support TypeScript type annotations) can't obtain this kind of information:

> TypeScript only emits type metadata for types available at run time, and does not emit type aliases, interfaces, or generics (as they do not have a JavaScript representation).

The amount of `MyService` instances depends on whether `MyService` was defined as component's provider or it was inherited from parent injector.

In the code above, `ComponentA` and `ComponentA1` can inherit `MyService` provider from parent injector, `ComponentB` can get a new instance with `providers: [MyService]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip adding a service using a module's provider array, and make it available from the root scope similarly to when you set *providedIn* to *root* in a service's **@Inject** decorator.  To do this use an **InjectionToken** with a factory method and set the *providedIn* value.

```
export const MyServiceAlphaToken = new InjectionToken<MyService<Alpha>>(
  'AlphaService', { factory: () => new MyService<Alpha>(), providedIn: 'root' });

export const MyServiceBetaToken = new InjectionToken<MyService<Beta>>(
  'BetaService', { factory: () => new MyService<Beta>(), providedIn: 'root' });
```

Then just inject with the **@Inject** parameter decorator.  The only issue is that it's not type safe - there's no comparison between the generic parameter specified in the token and the type specific in the service.

```
export class ComponentA {
  constructor(@Inject(MyServiceAlphaToken) alphaService: MyService<Alpha>) {}   
}

export class ComponentB {
  constructor(@Inject(MyServiceBetaToken) betaService: MyService<Beta>) {}
}
```

Also note, that there is no *deps* array like with providers.  Instead, use the **inject** function with the service class or InjectionToken for each dependency.

```
export const MyServiceWithDepdents = new InjectionToken<MyService<Omega>>('OmegaService', 
  { 
    factory: () => new MyService<Omega>(inject(DepAService), inject(DepBToken)), 
    providedIn: 'root'
  }
);
```

Comment: "The only issue is that it's not type safe" - I would say that this is a very critical point and that no one should wander around without type safety.