# How to get generic service using wrapper's class generic type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 5 and I'm trying to lower the amount of parameters are injected in my classes. I'm not looking to discuss if service locator is an anti-pattern or not, just understand if angular/typescript would allow me to do that, please.

I use service locator for that quite often, but there's one case I can't figure out how to solve and the few questions I read about generic injection did not help much :/

Here's my case:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent<T extends BaseModel> {
    protected recordId?: number = undefined;
    protected alertService: AlertService;
    protected translateService: TranslateService;
    protected router: Router;

    protected constructor(
        protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        protected store: BaseCrudStore<T>,
        protected baseType: { new(): T; }
    ) {
        this.record = new baseType();
        this.alertService = ServiceLocator.injector.get(AlertService);
        this.translateService = ServiceLocator.injector.get(TranslateService);
        this.router = ServiceLocator.injector.get(Router);
        //...
   }
}
```

I'd like `BaseCrudStore` to also be resolved using service locator instead of injecting it through the constructor. Is there a way to accomplish this? Is there a way to get my store using the service locator? As you can see, the `BaseCrudStore` is also generic and the generic parameter is the same one of the `BaseComponent` class.

So far I can't also fix injecting `ActivatedRoute`. It does inject, but (very likely) because of angular's structure it does not represent the current route, which makes sense thinking how it is built. If you know how to also fix this :)

I appreciate any help on this... my code is working 100%, it's just something that's been bothering me for a few months and I couldn't fix it.

ServiceLocator init:

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        ServiceLocator.injector = this.injector;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injection of Generic Services in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555744/injection-of-generic-services-in-angular)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167201/can-i-get-metadata-of-generic-type-in-typescript

Comment: @estus I'm sorry, I don't agree this is a dupe. I read the related question before posting here and it is not the same thing. Although the second link gets closer.

Comment: If you read them previously then you may know that it's impossible to use generics for that, thus you have XY problem. The question is focused on trying to solve existing problem with generics, while it isn't specific enough on what the real problem is. *It does inject, but (very likely) because of angular's structure it does not represent the current route* - why is so? Can you provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? You could pass `baseType` constructor as route `data`. I'd suggest to re-ask the question is more constructive form.

Comment: Ok, I'll reformulate my question then. About the route, it doesn't represent the current route if I inject it using service locator. If I inject it through the constructor, as seen in my example, it works fine, if I try to use service locator it doesn't represent the current route. It is not null, but it's "empty".

Comment: Then don't use service locator because this approach doesn't work with Angular hierarchical injectors. ServiceLocator isn't listed in the question, but it likely holds a reference to root injector, which is a mistake here.

Comment: @estus are you saying the way I'm using service locator is incorrect or that I shouldn't use it with ActivatedRoute? If it's the latter I was somewhat aware of that as I explained in my question, if it is the former, how should it be done, then? I pasted my service locator init in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: It really depends why you use it in the first place. The only good reason to expose a root injector is to use it in places that cannot obtain it normally (e.g. inside decorators). It's a hack and relying on the fact that a provider always belongs to root injector is wrong. ActivatedRoute is one of many things that can be messed up. Since a class is a component, it's unclear why you didn't inject real injector there. It would work as expected with `Injector`.

Answer (score 6):

If you already have an injector in your environment, you can try something like this:

```
protected store: Store<T>;

protected constructor() {
    this.store = AppInjectorService.injector.get<Store<T>>(Store);
}
```

Tested on Angular 6.