# Use of generics in angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

i would like to create a "generic" service to manage my modal dialogs coming from angular material.

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
  showModalDialog<T>(model: any = null) {
let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<T>;

dialogRef = this.dialog.open(T, {
  width: '460px',
  height: '600px',
  data: _.cloneDeep(model)
});

return dialogRef.afterClosed();
```

}

But it does not work, i get the following error :

> error TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

any idea of how i can do that ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injection of Generic Services in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555744/injection-of-generic-services-in-angular)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167201/can-i-get-metadata-of-generic-type-in-typescript

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, did you find the solution? Thank you!