# Resolve generic parameter in Angular Generic Service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a class structure where I need a `BaseModel` and a lot of `ChildModels`. Something like this

```
// BaseModel type

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BaseModel { 
    constructor() {
    }

    public _instanceUrl(): string {
        return '';
    };

    public url(): string {
        return 'BASE_URL_' + this._instanceUrl();
    };
}
```

---

```
// ChildModel type

import { BaseModel } from './base-model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ChildModel extends BaseModel {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public _instanceUrl(): string {
        return "CHILD_URL";
    }
}
```

---

```
// BaseService type

import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { BaseModel } from '../models/base-model';

@Injectable()
export class BaseService<T extends BaseModel> {

    private url: string; 
    constructor(private childInstance: T) { 
    } 

    public getUrl() {
        return this.childInstance.url();
    }
}
```

Here is my AppModule implementation:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ServicesModule
  ],
  providers: [BaseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is where I used the service

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService } from './modules/services/base-service/base-service.service';
import { ChildModel } from './modules/services/models/child-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-test';
  preventAbuse = false;

    constructor(private baseService: BaseService<ChildModel>) {
    }

    testHttp() {
        console.log(this.baseService.getUrl());
    }
}
```

I need to know if it is possible for *Angular* to provide the correct type `T` for the constructor of `BaseService` (in this case `ChildModel`). Right now, I am receiving an error, saying it cannot provide the construtor parameters.

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BaseService:
>   (?).

If I remove the parameter from the constructor of `BaseService`, the service is created OK. The problem is not injecting `BaseService`, the problem is injecting `BaseService` constructor parameter of type T. Also, I might potentially have hundreds of child classes, so I would like to avoid providing them all. Still, I am not sure this is possible.

I am using the latest version of Angular and Typescript

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.4
Angular: 7.2.7
typescript: 3.2.4
```

Here is a link to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgfywf)

Comment: possible dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555744/injection-of-generic-services-in-angular

Comment: @ABOS no, it is not a duplicate. I state that what I need is for Angular to provide the constructor parameter of type T for my generic Service. If I remove the constructor parameter, then yes, it is the same situation, but here the difference lies in the typed parameter of the service constructor. The problem is not injecting the generic service. It is injecting the type T to the generic service.

Comment: @ Alfredo, I think you are facing the same issue as the one I put above. So the question is how angular should instantiate service singletons when it comes across `baseService: BaseService<BaseModel>` and `baseService: BaseService<ChildModel>`. Should angular create 2 instances (then naming clash) or report error?

Comment: Angular is capable if detecting the correct instance. Assuming BaseService has an empty constructor then this works correctly in Angular : `constructor(baseService: BaseService<ChildModel>,baseModelService: BaseService<BaseModel>) {...}` The dependency injection works with no problem. The problem raises when BaseService defines a constructor with one parameter of type T (generic type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to use factory pattern, as suggested by [Injection of Generic Services in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555744/injection-of-generic-services-in-angular)

```
providers: [{
 provide: 'baseService',
 useFactory: (childModel: ChildModel) => (new BaseService<ChildModel>(childModel)),
 deps: [ChildModel]
}]

constructor(@Inject('baseService') private baseService: BaseService<ChildModel>) { 
  console.log(baseService.getUrl()); // output "BASE_URL_CHILD_URL"
}
```